# Should an empty case class be a single instance or not?

Tags: scala

I have a Scala case class:

```
case class DataClass(data: A, otherData: B, isEmpty: Boolean = false) {

  def someFunc(arg: C): D = ???

  ...
}
```

I have a factory for an empty case class. The primary use for the empty case class is the starting condition for using a `fold` to merge case classes.

```
object EntityTag {

   val empty: DataClass = DataClass(emptyA, emptyB, true)

   def merge(d1: DataClass, d2: DataClass): DataClass = ???

}
```

This is used as

```
dataList: Seq[DataClass] = ???
dataList.fold(DataClass.empty)(DataClass.merge)
```

Regarding the line `val empty: DataClass = DataClass(emptyA, emptyB, true)`, what are the reasons, if any, to not use a single instance of an empty DataClass object?

Is there any reason to prefer `val empty: () => DataClass = ...` or `def empty(): DataClass = ...`

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Why not merge it like `dataList.tail.fold(dataList.head)(DataClass.merge)` and avoid the empty object altogether?

Comment: @Sign I did not know about `tail`. That seems designed for this purpose, thank you.

Comment: The problem with `tail` is that if you call it on an empty `Seq` you'll throw an exception. It's better to handle the empty case explicitly, which is what you're being forced to do with the first argument to `fold`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are the reasons, if any, to not use a single instance

There are no reasons not to use a single instance of `DataClass` here to represent the empty value, since your case class is made up of immutable data and is not generic. Having a value named `empty` in the companion class to represent the empty case is both perfectly reasonable and idiomatic.

As a side note, the comment above suggesting that you use `dataList.tail` to avoid the empty object is in my view not very good advice. The `dataList` sequence may be empty, in which case calling `tail` on it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You could of course catch and handle these exceptions, but that's not generally a good idea—typically exceptions in Scala should be used only for actually exceptional problems, and an empty collection doesn't really fit that description. One of the benefits of using `fold` on your collection is that it forces you to handle the empty case.

To sum up: your code looks exactly right to me as it is. If you want to get fancy you could do something like provide a `cats.Monoid` instance for `DataClass` and then just use `dataList.combineAll`, but that's a matter of your taste and your tolerance for dependencies, and what you've got now is totally reasonable.